# Java streams to replace if else

Tags: java

How can use Java fliter and stream to replace the following code

```
public void demo(List<String> list,String id){
if(id!=null){
   return all the elements matching withid;
}else{
   return actual list passed in paramater;
}
```

Comment: Did you make any attempt to solve it yourself? There's a lot of resources already available which show how to use streams.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this :

```
  public List<String> demo(List<String> list, String id) {
    if (id != null) {
        return list.stream()
                   .filter(s -> s.equals(id))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else {
        return list;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If You want to remove the if/else You can try something like this:

```
public List<String> demo(List<String> list, String id) {
    return list.stream()
              .filter(s -> (id == null || s.equals(id)))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());

 }
```

I still prefer the if/else solution due to readability.